# FastAPI attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, python-import, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI following the [Bigger Applications - Multiple Files](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/) guide on how to split APIs into multiple files.

My project structure is the following:

```
─── src
    └── api
        ├── dependencies
        │   ├── db_connect.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── main.py
        └── routers
            ├── colors.py
            ├── __init__.py
            └── items.py
```

So I got an `api` package containing `main.py` and two subpackages `dependencies` and `routers`. In the files in `routers`, i.e. `colors.py` and `items.py` I import `db_connect.py` from the `ðependencies` package in the same way as shown in the guide, e.g.

colors.py

```py
from ..dependencies import db_connect
```

but I get the infamous error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` when I start `uvicorn --reload main:app` from inside the `api` package.

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** even just running `python main.py` from `src/api/` generates the error.

**SIMPLIFIED PYTHON CODE**

main.py

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from routers import items
from routers import colors

# Instantiate the FastAPI instance and include all the routers
app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(items.router)
app.include_router(colors.router)
```

items.py

```py
from ..dependencies import db_connect

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="items",
    tags=["items"],
    dependencies=[Depends(db_connect.get_collection)],
)
```

colors.py

```py
from ..dependencies import db_connect

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="colors",
    tags=["colors"],
    dependencies=[Depends(db_connect.get_collection)],
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
uvicorn --reload main:app
```

Relative imports from `main.py` require python to know what package it's in. It does this by looking in the module's `__name__` attribute which in this case would be `"main"`. It doesn't know it's inside the `api` package - that would require `__name__` to instead be `"api.main"` (or something nested further down like `"foo.bar.api.main"`) and so it can't do relative imports from the `api` package.

The simplest solution is to navigate up one level (to your `src` directory) and run:

```
uvicorn --reload api.main:app
```

and so `__name__` will instead be `api.main` and you'll see that the relative imports now work.

*Side note - There were a couple of small bugs in your example code. I assume your real code didn't have these based on the description of your observed error but mentioning here for completeness:*

- The imports in `main.py` were missing the leading dots, e.g. for items it should be `from .routers import items` rather than `from routers import items`
- The prefix in `colors.py` and `items.py` requires a `/` at the start